# Financial Company Logos API

Tags: api, logos

Is there a way to dynamically pull company logos for banks and brokerages into a webpage without individually downloading each logo or building a list of URL's to link to them directly?  I'm looking for any site that has an API to get company logos given a ticker symbol, company name, or website URL.

Comment: you can try to do a wrap around a standard google images search?

Comment: I doubt this exists. Even Google Finance and Yahoo Finance do not include company logos in their products.

Comment: @hexa: ... and wilfully ignore the notice "Image may be subject to copyright." Cue the lawyers in 3...2...1...

Comment: What about simply providing a link to their image/company logo? Wouldn't that be legal?

Comment: Now there is CompaniesLogo.com which is a database of logos from publicly traded companies. It also has a [stock and ETF logo API](https://companieslogo.com/logo-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't one.

You could build it, but note that most companies have restrictions on the use of their logos, so you'd need to have an agreement with each of them (that is probably why no such service exists).

Comment: While the resizing is done in your app/site, for the logos themselves, there’s another API for that: RiteKit Company Logo (REST): https://ritekit.com/api-demo/company-logo

In the RiteKit demo dashboard you can even test it without registration, login or API token. There’s a generous free tier and then, it’s very cheap to use at scale.

Let us know if you have questions or need help with anything.

Comment: you can get logo from url -> https://clearbit.com/logo